# Can I change node proeprty value in a AEM custom worklfow process?

Tags: workflow, aem

I have created a new workflow for activate later. It includes a custom workflow process step written by me. The custom step changes some properties of the payload step and then Activate Page process is called to activate the page. The changed properties are reflected in the author instance but not on the publish instance. Just wanted to confirm if this is possible or the workflow creates a copy of the node and then executes on it (like passing a parameter to a function)?
Thanks in advance :D

Answer (score 0):

It should work fine, however you have to commit changes using `resourceResolver.commit()`